# universal 3G USB keys

Tags: 3g, mobile-phone

Most of the 3g usb keys are sold and branded by mobile operators. Even if the name of the mobile operator is written on the key, will it always work for other operators and in other countries?

Comment: This entire depends on the bands the CDMA/GSM modem supports.  If it supports all bands then it can be used on any provider.  A 3G key unlikely.  Check the datasheet on the device.

Comment: @Matthew: The 3G stick will likely be locked to the network who branded it so you may need to get it unlocked. Also be aware that some networks have customised devices with proprietary firmware that might make it more difficult to use on another network. It really would depend on the specific device and where you are buying it from.

Answer (score 0):

The 3G stick is likely locked to the network by MCC/MNC (look up Mobile Country Code/Mobile Network Code), this means every try to use a different carrier/country (U)-SIM will lock you out asking for a "Network Code".

However if the 3G stick does not use a SIM card, it is a CDMA stick, and the carrier data is embedded in it's firmware.

P.S:  There are lots of ways of unlocking on the webs (look up for DC-Unlocker)
P.S.2: Unlocking your 3G Stick may be illegal / against contract in your country, so first read your contract with the carrier